# In spring security saml, Unable to GET /saml/login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jhipster, saml-2.0

I'm working with spring security SAML, following the example of SAML authentication found [here](https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample).

I'm implementing the contents of the file WebSecurityConfig.java, in my project. I've copied that file in the same package as other called SecurityConfiguration.java generated by [jHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/).

My problem is that when I try to perform a 3rd party login with my registered IDP, I get a 404 error saying "Cannot GET /saml/login" in the response body.

I'm trying to login using this URL:

```
http://localhost:9000/saml/login?idp=the id of the identity provider
```

What could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. When you are going to test SAML authentication, ensure you have your browser connected to the same port indicated by your server log.

If your server has opened port 8080 for example, your browser must be connected to port 8080. If you are working in development environment, use localhost:8080. Jhipster projects use port 9000 by default, which is the port where typescript compiler listens, to apply source changes on the fly. With SAML, avoid typescript mediation.

Also helps performing tests using @EnableWebSecurity(debug = true) in your security configuration bean, which writes in log the activated filters when making requests.